# What does L do?

Tags: c++, c, string

What does this do?

```
const wchar_t *s = L"test";
```

If wchar_t is two bytes on my machine, then why should we tell the compiler that the string should be treated in a way that each element is long i.e, *four* bytes in size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If in doubt, consult the standard (§6.4.5, String Literals):

> A *character string literal* is a
>   sequence of zero or more multibyte
>   characters enclosed in double-quotes,
>   as in `"xyz"`. A *wide string literal* is
>   the same, except prefixed by the
>   letter `L`.

Note that it **does not** indicate that each character is a `long`, despite being prefixed with the same letter as the `long` literal suffix.

Comment: Thanks, L was confusing me because it's the long literal suffix.

Answer (score 15):

The `L` means that string is a string of `wchar_t` characters, rather than the normal string of `char` characters.  I'm not sure where you got the bit about four bytes from.

From the spec section **6.4.5 String literals**, paragraph 2:

> A *character string literal* is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in **`"xyz"`**. A *wide string literal* is the same, except prefixed by the letter **`L`**.

And an excerpt from paragraph 5:

> For character string literals, the array elements have type **`char`**, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence; for wide string literals, the array elements have type **`wchar_t`**, and are initialized with the sequence of wide characters corresponding to the multibyte character
>   sequence, as defined by the **`mbstowcs`** function with an implementation-defined current locale.

Comment: The OP probably thought that the `L` meant `long`, i.e. 32 bits.

Comment: yes, but the OP probably doesn't know that, either. And to be fair, it's an easy mistake to make since the `L` suffix on an integer constant *does* turn it into a `long` (32 bits, usually). Suffice it to say that the OP is confused.

Comment: Presumably `wchar_t` is 4 bytes on his platform. Far as I know it's only 16 bits on Windows, among current popular platforms. Unicode requires 21 bits.

Answer (score 5):

`L` does not mean `long integer` when prefixing a string. It means each character in the string is a wide character.

Without this prefix, you are assigning a string of `char` to a `wchar_t` pointer, which would be a mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

It indicates a string of wide characters, of type `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what that `L` does, then why are you making an assertive statement about each array element being `long` ("four bytes in size")? Where did that idea with the `long` come from?

That `L` has as much relation to `long` as it has to "leprechaun" - no relation at all. The `L` prefix means that the following string literal consists of wide characters, i.e. each character has `wchar_t` type.

P.S. Finally, it is always a good idea to use const-qualified pointers when pointing to string literals: `const wchar_t *s = L"test";`.

Comment: I was confused since L suffix on integer turns it to long.

Comment: @shebaw: Yes, but in this case it is not even a suffix.